# Change Color of Image View Icons Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am programming an app in XCode 7.3 for iOS 9.3, and have a menu with different icons for each cell. I am trying to make the icons white, as they are default black, but `cell!.imageView?.tintColor()` seems to have no effect. Is there another method I could use?

EDIT: Here's the code after @LychmanIT's suggestion:

```
  switch indexPath.section {

    case 0: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "stuff.png")
    case 1: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "otherstuff.png")
    case 2: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "menu.png")
    default: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "error.png")

    }

    cell!.imageView?.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)

    cell!.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

EDIT: I fixed the problem by doing this:

```
cell!.imageView?.image! = (cell!.imageView?.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate))!
```

Comment: You need to use AlwaysTemplate rendering mode

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 3 this method became

```
func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImageRenderingMode) -> UIImage
```

Beside the method name, the solution proposed by [LychmanIT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6580886/lychmanit) didn't work  for me because the return of withRenderingMode method needs to be reassigned to the image that is passed to the imageView like:

```
let newImage = theImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
theImageView.image = newImage
theImageView.tintColor = .redColor
```

Regarding the question, it is also possible to run the .withRenderingMode method in the switch, like:

```
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "stuff.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    case 1: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "otherstuff.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    case 2: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "menu.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    default: cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(imageLiteral: "error.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    }
```

EDIT:

Additionally you can set the render mode of an image in **Asset Catalog**'s  **Attribute Instector** in the **Utilities** pane.

Answer (score 5):

Lets try this:

```
theImageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
theImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: Nice. Is there any advantage to doing it like:
https://gist.github.com/fabb/007d30ba0759de9be8a3

Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: I think there is so much excess code. But anyway its working :)

Comment: @LychmanIT It's not working for me for some reason. I put my code in the question: could you please look at it?

Comment: I fixed it with the above code, because `imageWithRenderingMode` returns the image needed

Answer (score 3):

```
imageView.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
imageView.tintColor = .red
```

OR you can use an extension below:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage {

    func overlayImage(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        color.setFill()

        context!.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.colorBurn)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        context!.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

        context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)
        context!.addRect(rect)
        context!.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fill)

        let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return coloredImage
    }

}
```